# Чем отличается Latency и Response time?

Tags: java, производительность

В небезывестной книге Фаулера написано:

Response time - промежуток времени, который требуется системе, чтобы обработать запрос извне.

Latency - минимальный интервал времени до получения какого либо отклика(даже если от системы более ничего не требуется)

Возможно из-за того, что это переведенная книга я не понимаю в чем разница. Объясните пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

**Latency** - задержка сигнала от вас до сервера

**Responce** time - задержка от вас до сервера и обратно (с учетом времени обработки на сервере)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разве Шипилёв не Latency постоянно измеряет? на кой черт он это делает если это сеть и с этим ничего не сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/low-latency/info